# Hacking characters in custom LCDs

Tags: lcd, datalogger, character-lcd, hacking

Say I have a device/instrument that has custom LCD for display with mix of text and graphic/icon on the corners. I want to log the values and feed it to the computer or say automate a response when the characters display a set of numerical values. How do I hack the LCD that way? Is there even a generic approach here? Is it just a matter of tapping into the the contacts for each line or pixel (for low resolution characters)?

Comment: Sending a photo of the LCD display and its interface (bonus points if we see a part number) would allow us to answer things more likely to be relevant. Some LCDs are directly driven by pixels, others have a high-level parallel interface, others have a serial interface, ...

Comment: Alright.... I think everybody that have answered this question have omitted (intentionally??) about the difference of passive and Active Matrix Addressing. RMS waveforms seem to be done with active addressing. While simpler m x n select is done with Passive Matrix Addressing. With the ubiquity of simple character (some icons on the side) LCDs, they're  almost DEFINITELY passive addressing. With that said it's actually easier than you guys insist it out to be, but still pretty hard as it is not simply tapping the contacts as with LED matices.

Comment: @kozner - your comment on one of the answers seems to suggest that you posted this question. Are you in fact the OP Majlin_Boo? If so I suggest you have these accounts merged to avoid confusion, or at least pick one & stick to it.

Comment: There are other instruments I'd like to hack (so hardly any pixel graphics), but this is what sparked the idea: https://www.amazon.ca/GEREE-Battery-Capacity-Indicator-Voltmeter/dp/B01HECEI5E/ I thought it'd be cool to see the plots of different types of battery technology.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say without details of the exact hardware being used but in general there will normally be a processor that is sending data to an LCD controller IC that then drives the pixels.

It would be a lot simpler and require a lot less wires if you could tap in to that communication link rather than the signals going to the physical display.

Comment: I agree. As an example, you have your LCD with a driver, and a microcontroller that sends commands to the driver using some serial data interface. If you tap in to that, you will be able to know what commands and data are sent. All you need to know how to interpret that data, so you will need to have the datasheet of the LCD that explains how it is driven.

Answer (score 1):

In general you would have to figure out the backplane and segment arrangement (usually at least triplexed if there are many display elements) and drive it with the right waveforms.

It's possible to generate the correct waveforms (DC component should not exceed a few tens of mV and RMS waveforms need to turn the required segments on) with ordinary GPIO pins and resistor networks, at least for simpler displays.

All told, it's not as straightforward as figuring out an LED display.

Comment: You need RMS waveforms for LCD? I didn't know that. I thought it would be very similar to driving LEDs... At least I had very basic experience in driving LED matrices.

Comment: LCD displays need AC from backplane to segment (almost zero DC content or the display will eventually be destroyed from electrochemical activity) and they don't have diodes so you have to run the waveforms such that the AC voltage exceeds or does not quite exceed the threshold for each segment you want on or off. Since that threshold is temperature-sensitive when the mux ratio is high (as in character displays) you need a contrast adjustment and/or temperature compensation.

Answer (score 1):

Digital cameras are available these days!! Just take pictures of the display as it shows the varied content. Then place the camera storage card in a USB card reader and extract the photos to the computer. Job done!!

Comment: That idea did cross my mind and I was going to mention it in my question as sarcasm. I held back.

Comment: It sounds more like he/she wants real-time actions so this is a good start, but put it in video mode and hook it up to a computer to detect certain images. Depending on the resolution of the LCD, this may be a far better approach than hacking the lcd.